# В каком месте в самой теме блокирует смену постоянных ссылок?

Tags: wordpress

**Всем привет!**

После длительных проверок и методов проб, выяснил следующее, что сама тема, блокирует изменение "Постоянных ссылок", а именно:

[image: Положение после того как я выбрал нужный формат]

[image: То, как отображается в строке браузера]

А хочу сделать, вот так - https://hotplus.com.ua/sample-post/

Вопрос следующий, какой файл, отвечает за эту функцию, где необходимо внести изменения?

Пожалуйста, не надо писать, что мол - смени тему, делов то - я Вас очень прошу. Тема премиальная как и все остальные которые были куплены. Никакие плагины не блокируют, проверено на 100%, соответственно данная идея отпадает.

Попробовал сменить тему и изменить структкру постоянных ссылок, моментально изменилось.

Что за файл, отвечает за эту функцию?

Спасибо заблаговременно за Ваши ответы и подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Структура постоянных ссылок сохраняется в базе данных в опции `'permalink_structure'`. Ищите такую строку в файлах темы, её обработка может быть где угодно. Скорее всего, они вешают свою функцию на фильтр `pre_update_option_permalink_structure` или просто на `pre_update_option`.

Возможны ещё всякие варианты с хуком на действия `update_option_permalink_structure`,  `updated_option` (чуть по-другому пишется, update**d**) или `permalink_structure_changed`. Но в любом случае будет использовано название опции: `'permalink_structure'`.